# Where to write a function/method in a django project

Tags: python, django, django-models

I am writing a function that normalizes gmail email address, transforming them from:

```
david.New+1234@gmail.com ==> davidnew@gmail.com
```

Otherwise, someone could sign up multiple times from a gmail account, for example. My current function is in `models.py` and looks like this:

```
def normalize_email(email):
    """
    Make sure people cannot register variations of the same email address
    """
    email = email.lower()
    name, domain = email.split('@')
    name = name.replace('.', '').split('+')[0]
    email = name + '@' + domain
    return email
```

This function is only called by the `User` model, so my question is where should this function/method best "live"? For example:

1) Within the User model as a regular method:

```
class User(models.Model):
    [fields here...]


    def normalize_email(self, email):
        ...
```

2) Within the User model as a classmethod

---

```
class User(models.Model):
    [fields here...]


    @classmethod
    def normalize_email(cls, email):
        ...
```

---

3) Within the User model as a static method

```
class User(models.Model):
    [fields here...]


    @staticmethod
    def normalize_email(email):
        ...
```

---

4) Within a User ModelManager:

```
class User(models.Model):
    [fields here...]
    objects = UserManager()
```

---

5) Outside of everything but in the models.py file as a regular function.

```
def normalize_email(email):
    ...

class User(models.Model):
    [fields here...]
```

---

Which of the above make sense to do and which do not? (for example, why would we not want to use choice X above, but choice Y or Z might make sense).

Comment: Looks to me in a `utils.py` module, since it is not specific to a model.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I see -- if I chose to write it within the `models.py` file, which of the above do you think would be the best place?

Comment: Then I would go for the `@staticmethod`, but this is rather opinion-based. But following the *high cohesion* design principle, I would say, store it in a separate file, since this has not much to do with the model layer anyway.

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem that makes sense, thanks. Finally: why would you choose a `staticmethod` over a `classmethod` in this case?

Comment: because the class itself is not a parameter in the function. A `@classmethod` should only be used if you process the `cls` itself (or a subchild might do that). But you can still override the method in a `User`'s subclass.

Answer (score 0):

I would advise as calling the function through "regular method", as this enables for listed features to be later added (if applicable).